# Can we integrate software to show Go and Chess positions?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

From [area51](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1423/board-card-games-exists-and-is-ready-for-your-questions/1447#1447):

Would it be possible to get something that would allow us to display Go and Chess positions on this site?

This has been raised as a possible objection towards integrating the Go and Chess StackExchange proposals here.

At this time, I don't know what exact software is needed, but I can research if necessary.  If anyone who sees this has an opinion on it, please let us know!

Comment: Uploading images wouldn't be sufficient? I know there's plenty of sites that let you drag and drop pieces onto a board and generate and image for you.

Comment: It would be good to use one of these on this answer: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/3379/curious-chess-situation/3388#3388 The uppercase/lowercase style is easy to read when there are only a few pieces, but with a whole board full of pieces...!

Comment: @tttppp, I've submitted an edit with a diagram. You're right, for complex positions, it's difficult. At least in this case, it helped to know that all pieces were on the board and were both attacking and defending other pieces.

Comment: I've read that this sort of support is also requested by several people wanting to make this a Magic the Gathering friendly environment. From the very simple :p: displaying a plains symbol sort of support to more involved :Atog: showing a picture of the Atog card. Is there substantial overhead or other issue involved with including these types of features?

Comment: Of course standard playing card smilies (or whatever) would be helpful too.  Slippery slope, where do you stop?

Comment: @stephen - I don't know.  If a strong consensus develops here on particular solutions then hopefully the devs will weigh in.

Comment: As a stopgap, for Chess there is a board image builder [here](http://www.chessvideos.tv/chess-diagram-generator.php) which works quite well. It's linked from the [tag:chess] tag wiki as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just as a quick update on the current state: @balpha [provided](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2446382#2446382) us with an excellent diagram renderer for Go. I'm quoting his answer from mGoSE:

> I doubt anybody working at Stack Exchange is going to take time to learn how to write an SGF parser just for a private beta site.

[Sounds like fun -- challenge accepted](http://code.google.com/p/bamboojoint/) :)

No, I didn't write an SGF parser, but the arguably most important thing – Sensei-style diagrams – will work now. It's not feature-complete (e.g. arrows aren't implemented), but at least you can see normal board situations.

```
$$Wcm31 This is the example diagram from the L19 forum thread http://lifein19x19.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&amp;t=226
$$ ---------------------------------------
$$ | . . . . . . . . . . . . . . ? ? ? ? ? |
$$ | . . . . . . . . . . . . . . ? ? ? ? ? |
$$ | . . . . . . . . . . . . . . ? ? ? ? ? |
$$ | . . X X X . . . . * . . . . O O O . . |
$$ | . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |
$$ | . . . B . . . . . C . . . . . W . . . |
$$ | . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |
$$ | . . . # . . . . . S . . . . . @ . . . |
$$ | . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |
$$ | . . . Y . . . . . T . . . . . Q . . . |
$$ | . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |
$$ | . . . Z . . . . . M . . . . . P . . . |
$$ | . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |
$$ | . . . . . 1 . 2 . 3 . 4 . 5 . . . . . |
$$ | . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |
$$ | . . . , . . . . . , . . . . . , . . . |
$$ | . . . a . b . c . d . x . y . z . . . |
$$ | . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |
$$ | . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |
$$ ---------------------------------------
```

Indent the markup by four spaces (i.e. make it a "code block", using Ctrl-K or the "{}" button).

My renderer uses the HTML5 Canvas, so your browser needs to support that – but these days, all of them except IE8 do. And even without the rendering, the diagrams in code blocks are of course still reasonably readable.

Comment: (doesn't work on met apparently)

Comment: @balpha - Any chance this could be adapted to implement Chess positions in a similar way? Much of your code looks reusable, and us poor Chess players need some love too...! ;)

Answer (score 3):

Hi, looks like you didn't get much help on this matter.
This link should get you started with GO diagrams:

http://senseis.xmp.net/?WebViewers

For chess:

http://www.enpassant.dk/chess/diaeng.htm

http://www.caissa.com/chess-tools/chess-diagram-generator.php

http://www.chessvideos.tv/chess-diagram-generator.php

Comment: Thanks for the pointers!

Answer (score 3):

For go refer to my older post:  https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/792/about-related-existing-sites/1913#1913

On lifein19x19 we have three different go specific features:

1. Sgf Diagrams
   A Sgf diagram represents a game tree that can be navigated.
   These are based on [Eidogo](http://eidogo.com/source) which is an AGPL licensed piece of javascript. The essential features require no server side support. There are some other in browser sgf viewers, but I think this one is the best. License might be a problem though.
2. Board diagrams
   Renders a one time snapshot of a board. The text describes the stones present on the board. There is no game tree.
   We use http://senseis.xmp.net/?GoWiki%2FSLtxt2PNG which is written on php 5. But if necessary I can write something similar in C#.
3. Go specific "smilies"
   These are short strings that the bbcode parser replaces with go specific icons such as numbered or marked stone. For example ":w10:" becomes a small image of a white stone with the number 10 on it.

Answer (score 0):

Since the [accepted answer](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/a/642/14474) gives relatively little detail, it may be useful to see [my more detailed answer](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1659/14474) to [How do we enter Go Boards on this site?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/987/how-do-we-enter-go-boards-on-this-site/1659#1659)