# How should I concisely represent a chess position in a question?

Tags: support, chess

If I want to ask a question about a certain chess position, how do I put it on-screen without the process being really tedious and the format impossible to decipher?  I can type it out in in text form, but not very easily.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Until we get software to [display chess positions](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/425/can-we-integrate-software-to-show-go-and-chess-positions) *(which IMHO is unlikely)*, I think the best option would be to take a screenshot of the position in your favorite chess program, and include it in the post.

If for some reason that is not an option, post the [FEN notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation) for the position.

Comment: Thank you!

Comment: @drm65 In fact you can use an online diagram generator together with the FEN notation: http://webchess.freehostia.com/diag/index.php?lang=english (Try the preview button)

Comment: I've included a link to a site that allows multiple setup methods, including drag-and-drop and FEN, to the chess tag wiki. Any on- or offline generator should be fine, though.