# Please implement the Chess replayer on Board and Card Games

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, chess

The [Chess](https://chess.stackexchange.com/) beta site [now has a cool replayer](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/can-we-implement-a-replayer-for-chess-analysis-on-the-site), to allow Chess games/positions to be described, rendered and walked through. It's been around for a couple of months now.

We've been [asking for this for some time](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/425/can-we-integrate-software-to-show-go-and-chess-positions). We already have a nice [go](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/go)  [renderer](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/a/642/50), and [basic card-linking functionality](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/726/please-add-support-for-the-magic-autocard-window) for [magic-the-gathering](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering), both of which have been great. Now that something has been written for [chess](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess), our [6th most popular game](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tags), could we please have the same functionality enabled here?

Comment: Might it be better for questions with that level of complexity to be migrated to the chess site? (If the beta fails, the questions could be brought back here, and the replayer enabled at that point.)

Comment: @mattdm - No. 1) It's a great way to present even a static board. 2) All Chess questions are on topic here, even/especially complex ones. 3) The question of whether a separate site is needed for Chess is quite undecided, hence the beta. 4) The existence of the Chess beta says nothing about the existence of Chess questions on this site. That beta is in no way more valid than this one.

Answer (score 5):

This would be nice on occasion, but... At present, it would interfere with the Go renderer. Until such a time as these can be integrated, I would recommend just using [the dedicated Chess site](https://chess.stackexchange.com/) for questions that would benefit from this.