# How do we enter Go Boards on this site?

Tags: support, markdown

I had asked a question (now deleted) on meta.stackexchange about a Go-version of stackexchange. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164930/go-stackexchange-com

It was already tried http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11942/game-of-go which closed, so I wanted to try asking questions on here.

They also mentioned a javascript library for encoding go boards which may have been implemented on here already.  And I wanted to know how that works.

The long term goal, would be to use this existing site to host questions, and maybe it can become standard for American go players.

Answer (score 9):

[go](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/go) questions are most welcome here. In fact, the Go site that you mention was *merged* with this site. As you can [see here](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/go?sort=votes&pagesize=15), a number of interesting Go questions have been asked and answered here.

We support graphical Go boards through custom markup. This is [described here](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/a/642/50). Here is an example of a rendered board, used in a question: [Why did black avoid the straightforward capture here?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/5540/why-did-black-avoid-the-straightforward-capture-here)

Answer (score 2):

My favorite way to enter Go boards is to find an old question with a Go board, enter the edit mode, copy the board and paste it into my new question/answer. (Cancelling the edits on the old question, of course.) That gives a nice starting place for my new diagram.

Sometimes I look for an existing diagram with a set-up similar to what I want to make, but editing them is easy enough that usually I just go with the first one I find. Searching on [go](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/go) is good for finding existing diagrams.

Answer (score 2):

You can code diagrams of as much of a board as you want, with a **maximum of 10** numbered moves and various highlights and letters. This function only works **on the main site**, not here on meta. Alternatively you can upload an image (<kbd>Ctrl-G</kbd> or see the [help](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/editing-help#images)).

### Notation

A diagram has to be formatted as a “code block”, i.e. indented by four spaces, which may be done using <kbd>Ctrl-K</kbd> or the <kbd>{}</kbd> button on the edit toolbar. Be sure to include blank lines before and after a diagram; one also seems to need normal text lines between diagrams. After a short pause, if a diagram is correctly coded, it should appear properly formatted in the preview (except here on meta).

The notation used in diagrams is a subset of that used by [Sensei’s Library](https://senseis.xmp.net); the simplest features may be learnt from the samples below.
The notation is specified in: https://senseis.xmp.net/?HowDiagramsWork,
but arrows and lines appear not to be supported here.
On any of their pages, click the <kbd>Edit Page</kbd> button to view or copy the code for the diagrams.

There is also a description of the notation here: https://lifein19x19.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=226 – but note that the `[go]`…`[/go]` tags are not used on this site. That page also has places to click to show the code for the examples, which is handy for cut & paste.

This answer reports that support for diagrams has been introduced, but gives little help: https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/a/642/14474

The [tag-wiki](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tags/go/info) also summarises the notation (and refers here).

#### Stones, points and marks

- White stone: `O`; with circle: `W`, square: `@`, triangle: `Q`, cross: `P`
- Black stone: `X`; with circle: `B`; square: `#`, triangle: `Y`, cross: `Z`
- Empty point: `.`; with circle: `C`, square: `S`, triangle: `T`, cross: `M`;  hoshi: `,`; letters:`a`–`z`; blank: `_`
- Borders & corners: `-` / `|` / `+` (outside the playing area)
- Numbered stones: `1`–`9`, then `0` (the highest possible), starting with 1 or a number you specify after `m` in the header line.

### Tools

Herman Hiddema has a very intuitive tool to create diagram code interactively: http://hiddema.nl/diagrammer/

Sensei’s Library offers a tool to convert [SGF](https://senseis.xmp.net/?SGF) files to diagrams:http://senseis.xmp.net/tools/sgf2diagram.php.

### Tips

As already mentioned, there are many possibilities for cut & paste using samples here, on the main site or elsewhere.

If editing a whole-board diagram, you may find it helpful to expand the edit box (drag the bottom down) and zoom your browser out (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl--</kbd> in Firefox) so as to see all your code and the result at the same time.

Please use the `c` (show coordinates) option if people are likely to want to refer to points on the board in comments.

### References in text

Note that Unicode includes a few handy characters, which you can cut and paste from here:

> ⓿ ❶❷❸❹❺❻❼❽❾❿ ⓫⓬⓭⓮⓯⓰⓱⓲⓳⓴ 
>   ⓪  ①②③④⑤⑥⑦⑧⑨⑩ ➀➁➂➃➄➅➆➇➈➉ *(second group slightly larger)*
>   ▲△ ◯⬤ *note<sup>1</sup>*

### Samples

- *this answer cannot show the results of these samples (unless we upload images), because diagrams are not supported here on meta*

Any of the following samples can be pasted into your post as they stand (or all at once!); they are already indented by four spaces as required. Of course an existing question with a similar diagram may also editted to get a

For convenience, here is an almost empty board with only two moves, with a header ‘`Bcm1`’ meaning black moves first (`B`), coördinates should be shown (`c`) and the first move should be numbered 1  (`m1`). In the rest of the diagram `.` and `,` represent normal vacant points and hoshi points respectively; `-`/`+`/`|` all (interchangeably) represent edges; numbered moves from 1 to 10 are coded `1`, `2`, … `9`, `0`:

#### Empty boards

```
(normal text followed by a blank line)

    $$Bcm1 (title of diagram here)
    $$ +-------------------+
    $$ |...................|
    $$ |...................|
    $$ |...2...............|
    $$ |...,.....,.....,1..|
    $$ |...................|
    $$ |...................|
    $$ |...................|
    $$ |...................|
    $$ |...................|
    $$ |...,.....,.....,...|
    $$ |...................|
    $$ |...................|
    $$ |...................|
    $$ |...................|
    $$ |...................|
    $$ |...,.....,.....,...|
    $$ |...................|
    $$ |...................|
    $$ |...................|
    $$ +-------------------+

(more normal text preceded by a blank line)
```

Here is the top left quarter of the board:

```
    $$Bcm1 (top left)
    $$ +----------
    $$ |..........
    $$ |..........
    $$ |..........
    $$ |...,.....,
    $$ |..........
    $$ |..........
    $$ |..........
    $$ |..........
    $$ |..........
    $$ |...,.....,
```

And the top right:

```
    $$Bcm1 (top right)
    $$ ----------+
    $$ ..........|
    $$ ..........|
    $$ ..........|
    $$ ,.....,...|
    $$ ..........|
    $$ ..........|
    $$ ..........|
    $$ ..........|
    $$ ..........|
    $$ ,.....,...|
```

And the bottom left:

```
    $$Bcm1 (bottom left)
    $$ |...,.....,
    $$ |..........
    $$ |..........
    $$ |..........
    $$ |..........
    $$ |..........
    $$ |...,.....,
    $$ |..........
    $$ |..........
    $$ |..........
    $$ +----------
```

And the bottom right:

```
    $$Bcm1 (bottom right)
    $$ ..........|
    $$ ..........|
    $$ ..........|
    $$ ,.....,...|
    $$ ..........|
    $$ ..........|
    $$ ..........|
    $$ ..........|
    $$ ..........|
    $$ ,.....,...|
    $$ ----------+
```

And here are empty 13 x 13 and 9 x 9 boards:

```
    $$Bcm1 (title of diagram here)
    $$ +-------------+
    $$ |.............|
    $$ |.............|
    $$ |.............|
    $$ |...,.....,...|
    $$ |.............|
    $$ |.............|
    $$ |......,......|
    $$ |.............|
    $$ |.............|
    $$ |...,.....,...|
    $$ |.............|
    $$ |.............|
    $$ |.............|
    $$ +-------------+

    $$Bcm1 (title of diagram here)
    $$ +---------+
    $$ |.........|
    $$ |.........|
    $$ |..,...,..|
    $$ |.........|
    $$ |....,....|
    $$ |.........|
    $$ |..,...,..|
    $$ |.........|
    $$ |.........|
    $$ +---------+
```

#### Ear-reddening move

And – largely for fun – here is the [ear-reddening move](https://senseis.xmp.net/?EarReddeningMove), where `X` and `O` stand for unnumbered stones and `#` for highlighted stones, the move coded `1` is to be numbered White 118 and the three moves after the ear-reddening move (127) are shown as `a`, `b`, `c`:

```
    $$Wcm118 The ear-reddening move (127)
    $$ ---------------------
    $$ -.........XO1.......-
    $$ -...2ab...XOXO.OOX..-
    $$ -..3O.X..OXXOO.OX...-
    $$ -...,.....,.XXX.,X..-
    $$ -.....4....X....XX..-
    $$ -..O............XOO.-
    $$ -....c........OOOXXX-
    $$ -..............XOOOX-
    $$ -.........0..XOOXXX.-
    $$ -...,.....,..OOX,XO.-
    $$ -..O...........OXXO.-
    $$ -..............OXOX.-
    $$ -............O.OXOO.-
    $$ -..5......#.#O.OX...-
    $$ -......X.9..#OXOXO..-
    $$ -..X,X..X.,.#OOXOO..-
    $$ -.....8OXO.OOXXXXOO.-
    $$ -......6OXOO.OXX.XO.-
    $$ -........7..O.X.X.X.-
    $$ ---------------------
```

<sup>1</sup> These are large circles, normal circles ○● look too small.