# Should this question about fonts be closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

The recent question [Designing - How do you approach finding the right font for your game?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/24387/50) has been put on-hold as "primarily opinion-based".

Should this question really be closed? I am concerned that

1. Most of us don't know much about fonts, so it's hard to judge the subjectivity of the question.
2. There is a desire to migrate the question to a site that might be more suitable.
3. Reading [this answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/24390/50), I find myself thinking this is an existence proof for exactly the kind of non-subjective answer, written by a game designer, that makes this question acceptable.

Regarding the second point, it is [well established](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/unix-and-ubuntu-why-both/) that a question can overlap multiple sites, and can therefore be on-topic for both. In particular, this [B&CG specific-discussion](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/995/are-we-as-the-board-and-card-game-stackexchange-too-broad-in-defining-ourselve) describes our current consensus.

Answer (score 3):

I think it should be reopened.

The question isn't asking what font should I use, it is asking how do I figure out what font I should use. The first question I agree would be opinion based, but the one that is actually being asked is not. As Joe's answer shows it does have an answer that is objective.

As freekvd says in his answer this is not currently answerable by a graphics designer, but I think that is perfectly ok. Here we can help them define what sorts of things they should look for in the font (does it need to be readable from across the table, are you trying to get a sci-fi feel, etc.) and once they know the sorts of things they should look for they can then go to GD.SE and ask them "I am looking for a font with X, Y, and Z characteristics. What are good fonts that meet those criteria?"

Comment: Agreed. Maybe it just needs to be edited somehow so that everyone will stop assuming the OP is asking for specific font choices?

Answer (score 2):

I did some research, and I was wrong to flag for migration. According to [this abnormally large post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/32515/254466):

> [Migration] should only be used when you are 100% certain that not only does the question not belong on the site where it was asked, but that it **absolutely does** belong on the site you are targeting with the migration.

I am 100% sure that it belongs on Graphic Design. I am only 60% sure that it does not belong here. 60% is not good enough.

## This does not mean the question is reopenable.

Just because it belongs here does not mean that it is a well-written question. I was not among the original close voters, but if I were, I would have used a custom reason:

> This question does not contain enough details to provide a solid answer in a reasonable amount of space.

Arguably, voting to close as Too Broad would also be correct here. In any case, it doesn't matter where the question ultimately ends up - it *needs* more detail.

Comment: Do you still think that your custom close reason (or Too Broad) are still valid on the question in light of the existing answers?

Comment: @murgatroid99 Yes. The too broad close reason means "you can imagine a book being written on the topic". I can imagine a somewhat short book being written on this topic (hence the "arguably"). The custom reason seems more educational: it describes my actual problem with the question.

Answer (score -1):

I think the answer to this question is absolutely relevant for B&CGSE, but those who can best answer it are over at Graphics Design. As mentioned, they have a whole category for font selection. They might not have the same experience with board games, but they do have a lot of experience with a wide range and variety of all-purpose objects including packaging, pamphlets, magazines, outdoor advertising, etc.

It is a common misconception that graphic design is only about look and feel. Functional design is much more important to a good designer.

That said, after coming home from work today I checked with my wife, a graphic designer, and she said the question is unanswerable in its current form. There are too many different card sizes and text amounts that would lead to different font choices. Catan resource cards are small, and on hand. Machi Koro has regular sized cards that are constantly on the table, at an angle. Dixit has large cards, where text only appears as part of the artwork.

In its current form, the question should remain closed. If it's made more specific, it could be re-opened here, or on Graphic Design.

Comment: My number one takeaway from this answer was that you had to ask your wife, a **graphic designer**, whether the question was suitable.

Comment: Gotta love the irony, right?

Comment: I wouldn't be so eager to say it's unanswerable. It's definitely true that there's not enough information there to choose a font, but it's not asking for that. It's asking about the process - what things do you need to consider? And that's a really helpful question to answer. Sure, we could pin the OP down on their current game, and they'd get a useful answer, and it might help a few people in the future, but we could also provide starting points and directions that'll be useful for a lot more people.