# Go boards fail to render on mobile

Tags: bug

As described in [How do we enter Go Boards on this site?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/987/3389), it is possible to create a graphical representation of a Go board on this site. However, it displays differently on different devices.

When I look at [this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/39470/3389) on my Mac (Safari, Firefox, Chrome), it appears like this:

[image]

But on my iPhone (Safari), it appears like this:

[image]

I have also been able to reproduce the bottom behavior by spoofing my user agent to a mobile device in both Safari and Firefox. <s>I assume it would also render this way if I tried it on a real Android device.</s> Cascabel reports that it renders correctly with Chrome on an Android device, so it may be limited to Apple devices.

Could we have this fixed so that Go boards are properly rendered on both desktop and mobile?

Comment: It works fine in Chrome on Android. https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7G5M.png

Comment: @Cascabel What sized device are you using? I just tried on an iPad and it rendered correctly.

Comment: Pixel 2. I actually reproduced the issue earlier with mobile emulation in Chrome on Linux (I think set to Nexus 5X) but I can't seem to anymore. I do see the underlying text representation for a flash on refresh; I wonder if the rendering code was just failing to load previously?

Comment: @Cascabel Still fails on my iPhone SE, so if they are working on fixing it, it doesn’t seem complete yet.

Comment: I didn't meant to suggest that SE (or really anyone) was working on fixing anything, just that it could be an intermittent bug or just trouble loading some script somewhere.

Comment: This is still broken @cascabel of we want it fixed, it's it better to ask a new question?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this isn't even just about mobile devices: it's just about the site mobile layout missing whatever functionality makes Go boards work.

---

Head to that question ([Is this a correct formal heuristic for invalid moves due to Ko?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/39470/is-this-a-correct-formal-heuristic-for-invalid-moves-due-to-ko)) and note how all the Go boards work.

Scroll all the way to the bottom, and click the bottom-left-most link, **Mobile**, to switch to the mobile layout. Your cursor won't treat it like a link, but it will work.

[image: "mobile" link to switch to mobile site]

Now that we're in the mobile layout, notice how all the Go boards are just code blocks.

Scroll all the way to the bottom again and click the last link in the footer, **full site**, to return to the full site:

[image: "full site" link to leave the mobile layout]

We'll be back on the desktop site and all of the Go boards are working.

---

You can do the same in reverse for any mobile device to witness all the Go boards working just fine as long as you're in **full site mode.**