# Can formatting help please include links to community-specific features?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

This community has support for [go](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/go)-board diagrams, [chess](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess) and no doubt many other useful features, but the basic [formatting help](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) does not include links to descriptions of them.
As a consequence the way of using them seems to be <kbd>edit</kbd>+<kbd>copy</kbd>+<kbd>cancel</kbd>+<kbd>paste</kbd>+<kbd>hack</kbd>+<kbd>pray</kbd> or searching on meta, which worked for me for [go](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/go), but involved a little more following of links and experimenting than seemed ideal.

Since that seemed unnecessarily indirect and laborious, I ended up adding [another answer with essentials, links and samples](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1659/14474) to [How do we enter Go Boards on this site?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/987/how-do-we-enter-go-boards-on-this-site/1659#1659) . Since I found the necessary information via [an answer](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/a/642/14474) to [Can we integrate software to show Go and Chess positions?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/425/can-we-integrate-software-to-show-go-and-chess-positions/642#642) although the question sounds less relevant, I also added [an answer there](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1660/14474) linking to my detailed answer.

It would be helpful if the help pages for formatting (or the pages for creating posts) were to make it easier to discover the appropriate descriptions. Since these pages appear to be largely generic, it may be helpful to have a standard text saying how to find community-specific markup, which could involve a new special-purpose meta tag such as [community-specific-markup](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-specific-markup).

Comment: I would say if you want to do this crate meta questions that contain the specifics of the formatting that you want to explain how to use, and then link to that meta question from inside the tag wiki.

Comment: @Malco: When you say _the tag wiki_ do you mean [tag:go] or [tag:chess]? While not where I would automatically look, I think it is a good idea. _Later:_ I have just checked for Go, and there were some basic instructions, which I extended with a link to my fuller answer.

Comment: @PJ by tag wiki I am referring to these pages eg: [go tag wiki](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tags/go/info), [chess tag wiki](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tags/chess/info). Though I agree it isn't that intuitive, there is precedent (see [mtg tag wiki](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tags/magic-the-gathering/info) for how to format the autocard).