# Markdown mods for Magic the Gathering?

Tags: discussion, magic-the-gathering, markdown

I have seen that there is a special tag supported in the markup for Magic the Gathering [mtg...], but it's not documented in:

https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/editing-help

1) What is the full description of that feature?  (Based on this question: [Can the Magic card auto link feature be improved?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1152/can-the-magic-card-auto-link-feature-be-improved), it looks like this feature has been changing.)

2) Are there other markdown mods that aren't in the documentation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you include `[mtg:Card Name]`, it is equivalent to writing `[Card Name](http://www.wizards.com/magic/autocard.asp?name=Card%20Name)`. That means that it creates a link, where the link text is the name of the card, and it links to the gatherer entry for that card. It is important to note that due to a gatherer bug, a card with an apostrophe (such as *Acolyte's Reward*) in its name cannot be properly linked this way.

There is also apparently a [special syntax](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/425/can-we-integrate-software-to-show-go-and-chess-positions/642#642) for Go boards.

Comment: We also support rendering for Go boards with special syntax: http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/425/can-we-integrate-software-to-show-go-and-chess-positions/642#642

Comment: Is this still up-to-date?

Comment: The general idea is still the same: `[mtg:Card Name]` gives you a link to that card. The link URL may have changed since that but that's really an implementation detail.

Answer (score 2):

Can we add some information about those special markdowns (which I assume are specific only to Boardgames SE) to [help pages](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/editing-help)? 
I only found out about this feature from some random comment.

Comment: Unfortunately we do not have the ability to edit any of the help pages - they're shared by the entire network and authored by SE staff. We can only edit our [on topic help page](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

I think it is worth adding an answer here, that this syntax is documented on the documentation page for the [Magic the Gathering Tag](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tags/magic-the-gathering/info).